# ¿Cómo elimino el último elemento de mi array de objetos?

Tags: c++, array, diseño-de-clases

Quiero hacer un método que **elimine el último elemento de mi array** de equipos de fútbol sala. *LigaFutbolSala* es una clase que contiene un array con diferentes *FutbolSala* (estos últimos son los equipos). Quiero hacer dicha eliminación **sin recurrir a constructores por defecto**.

```
LigaFutbolSala::LigaFutbolSala(int identificador, string ciudad) {
   this->identificador = identificador;
   this->ciudad = ciudad;
   equiposFutbolSala = new FutbolSala * [numMax];
   cont = 0;
}

void LigaFutbolSala::eliminarEquipoFutbolSala() {

   if (cont > 0) {
       // AQUI QUIERO HACER LA ELIMINACIÓN
   }
   else {
       cout << "No hay equipos en la liga" << endl;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu "identificador" es la posicion, creo que podria ser algo asi como:

```
`Lista::Eliminar(int identificador){
  if(identificador<cont && identificador>=0){
    for(int i = 0; i<cont; i++){
      arreglo[i]=arreglo[i+1];
    }cont--;
   }
 }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo lo siguiente:

1. Tu array equiposFutbolSala es un arreglo de punteros a una clase FútbolSala
2. Cont apunta al siguiente elemento libre del arreglo.

Entonces

1. En tu constructor debes agregar equiposFutbolSala[0]=null.
2. En LigaFutbolSala::eliminarEquipoFutbolSala() debes hacer:

```
   if(cont>0) {
// Al menos hay un equipo en la lista.
       --cont; // Como Cont apunta al siguiente elemento libre o último elemento libre de la lista entonces retrocedes uno para que el último ingresado se vuelva el último libre;
       }

   FutbolSala * fs = equiposFutbolSala[Cont];
// Por si acaso
  if(fs!=NULL) {
         // Eliminas la memoria utilizada
        delete fs;
            equipoFutbilSala[Cont]=NULL
}
Else{
     // Liga sin equipos
}
   ;
```

3. Al agregar equipos debes tener presente:

```
     if(Cont>=num_max){
     // Liga completa
           return;
  }

   FutbolSala *fs = new FutbolSala();
//Llenas los datos de fs

// agregas al array
      equiposFutbolSala[Cont]=fs;
     Cont++;
    if(Cont<num_max)
          equiposFutbolSala[Cont]=NULL;
```

Nota: Ahora lo mejor es utilizar la STD que tiene clases que manejan muy bien los punteros y arreglos y no tienes que preocuparte de ello. Una de ellas es la clase vector<>.

Comment: No me deja igualar equipoFutbilSala[Cont] a NULL. Me da el siguiente error: "ningún operador  = coincide con estos operandos los tipos operando son: FutbolSala = int".

Comment: Pero entre nces yo array es de enteros. En el constructor haces equiposFutbilSala=new FutbolSala*[]. FutbolSala es la na clase?

Comment: Eliminé mi comentario anterior porque estaba errado.bHicebuna prueba y para que te salga el error que dices es porque estás haciendo *equiposFutbolSala[Cont]=NULL y debería de ser sin el *.